# Any reason an HP C7499A DVD ROM shouldn't work on an old Sun Ultra Enterprise II?

Tags: solaris, hardware, dvd

I'm trying to switch from a CD-ROM to a DVD-ROM on an old Sparc Ultra Enterprise II. I got this C7499A but I can't seem to access anything on it. I thought that since it's SCSI it should work even though DVD's weren't around when this Sparc was made. Is it probable that the drive is just bad?

Answer (score 2):

I have no specific knowledge of the setup you describe, but SCSI does have the possibility of sending device-specific commands. You could easily be out of luck even if the drive is good.

When you boot Solaris, does the C7499A go through some power-up/Built-in-test type flashing lights and spinning up? After Solaris is running, can you see the DVD-ROM drive with whatever command Solaris uses to do that (I can't recall what I used to use, and google doesn't want to help)?

The boot PROM on Sun machines used to have some commands like "probe-scsi". Can you get the machine into the boot PROM to see what it says about hardware?

Also, check the cabling. If you're using flat-ribbon SCSI cables, always be suspicious of them. They go bad if you touch them too much.